# Is there a benefit to decreasing the size of my NVARCHAR columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, nvarchar

I have a SQL Server 2008 database that stores millions of rows. There are several NVARCHAR columns that will *never* exceed the current max length of the column, nor get close to it due to application constraints.

i.e.
The Address NVARCHAR field has a length of 50 characters, but it'll never exceed 32 characters.

Is there a performance benefit or space saving benefit to me reducing the size of the NVARCHAR column to what it's *actual* max length will be (i.e. in the case of the Address field, 32 characters). Or will it not make a difference since it's a variable length field?

Comment: There isn't any performance benefit, but it can help with enforcing business rules.  If you want to make sure that the data **never** exceeds 32 characters, it would be a good idea to set the limit.  For example, if you want to use a fixed-width text box to show it, that would be a good way of ensuring that your text isn't cut off.

Comment: Might be helpfull regarding memory usage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082746/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the number of characters in NVARCHAR is mainly for validation purposes. If there is some reason why you don't want the data to exceed 50 characters then the database will enforce that rule for you by not allowing extra data.

If the total row size exceeds a threshold then it can affect performance, so by restricting the length you could benefit by not allowing your row size to exceed that threshold. But in your case, that does not seem to matter.
The reason for this is that SQL Server can fit more rows onto a Page, which results in less disk I/O and more rows can be stored in memory.

Also, the maximum row size in SQL Server is 8KB as that is the size of a page and rows cannot cross page boundaries. If you insert a row that exceeds 8KB, the extra data will be stored in a row overflow page, which will likely have a negative affect on performance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no expected performance or space saving benefit for reducing your `n/var/char` column definitions to their maximum length. However, there may be other benefits.

- The column won't accidentally have a longer value inserted without generating an error (desirable for the "fail fast" characteristic of well-designed systems).
- The column communicates to the next developer examining the table something about the data, that aids in understanding. No developer will be confused about the purpose of the data and have to expend wasted time determining if the code's field validation rules are wrong or if the column definition is wrong (as they logically should match).
- If your column does need to be extended in length, you can do so with potential consequences ascertained in advance. A professional who is well-versed in databases can use the opportunity to see if upcoming values that will need the new column length will have a negative impact on existing rows or on query performance—as the amount of data per row affects the number of reads required to satisfy queries.

Answer (score 0):

In [[N]Varchar(4000) and Performance](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/nvarchar4000-and-performance) on sqlservercentral.com Eddie Wuerch commented:

> When estimating the width of a row in order to request memory, varchar
> and nvarchar columns are assumed to be half full. A varchar(2000)
> column would cause a 1000-byte memory request per row, and an
> nvarchar(2000) would cause a 2000-byte request (1/2 of 2000 = 1000
> characters * 2 bytes per character).

And

> The maximum length of any of the values is less than 60 bytes, with
> 95% of the values at 37 bytes or less. With the proper data type, this
> query needs less than 256KB to run completely, including the SORT
> operator. By blowing up the possible sizes for the variable character
> types, significant extra memory is allocated and wasted. All of the
> queries tested return the exact same data.

He created this sample

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ColumnSizes(
    id    int    NOT NULL,
    NVarChar64 nvarchar(64) NOT NULL, 
    NVarChar256 nvarchar(256) NOT NULL, 
    NVarChar1024 nvarchar(1024) NOT NULL, 
    NVarChar4000 nvarchar(4000) NOT NULL,
    NVarCharMax nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    VarChar64  nvarchar(64) NOT NULL,
    VarChar256 nvarchar(256) NOT NULL,
    VarChar1024 nvarchar(1024) NOT NULL,
    VarChar8000 varchar(8000) NOT NULL,
    VarCharMax varchar(max) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pkColSz PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id) 
)
GO
INSERT dbo.ColumnSizes 
(
        id, NVarChar64, NVarChar256, NVarChar1024, 
        NVarChar4000, NVarCharMax,  VarChar64, VarChar256, 
        VarChar1024, VarChar8000, VarCharMax
)
SELECT object_id, name, name, name, name, name, 
       name, name, name, name, name 
FROM sys.all_objects;
```

Using XE sessions to grab memory usage he concluded

> The maximum length of any of the values is less than 60 bytes, with
> 95% of the values at 37 bytes or less. With the proper data type, this
> query needs less than 256KB to run completely, including the SORT
> operator. By blowing up the possible sizes for the variable character
> types, significant extra memory is allocated and wasted. All of the
> queries tested return the exact same data. The [Used %] column shows
> that storing the sample data in an NVarchar(4000) resulted in 99% of
> the granted memory being wasted.

```
 TestColumn     EstRowWidth IdealMemKB  GrantedMemKB UsedMemKB   Used % Granted %
 -------------- ----------- ----------- ------------ ----------- ------ ---------
 id             11          NULL        NULL         NULL        NULL   NULL
 NVarChar64     75          NULL        NULL         NULL        NULL   NULL
 VarChar64      75          NULL        NULL         NULL        NULL   NULL
 NVarChar256    267         NULL        NULL         NULL        NULL   NULL
 VarChar256     267         NULL        NULL         NULL        NULL   NULL
 NVarChar1024   1035        5344        5344         216         4      100
 VarChar1024    1035        5344        5344         216         4      100
 NVarChar4000   4011        11872       11872        216         1      100
 VarChar8000    4011        11872       11872        168         1      100
 NVarCharMax    4035        11936       11936        272         2      100
 VarCharMax     4035        11936       11936        224         1      100
```